# Java DTO Design - Public members

Tags: java, json, serialization, dto, getter-setter

I'm designing a DTO that will be serialized to JSON. The serializing framework kept complaining that all the members of my DTO should be public, and that the DTO should have public no-args CTOR.

I was wondering which of these two approaches is better, in your opinion, and why:

1) No getters/setters

```
public MyClass {
    public int someField;
    public String someOtherField;
}
```

2) All getters/setters

```
public MyClass {
    private int someField;
    private String someOtherField;

    public int getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    public String getSomeOtherField() {
        return someOtherField;
    }

    public void setSomeField(int someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }

    public void setSomeOtherField(String someOtherField) {
        this.someOtherField = someOtherField;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of framework are you using?

Comment: In the new Java EE no-getters/setters is supported for JPA but I still did not see it for EL. (I might be erring.)

Comment: I wanted to recommend you [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) as it works with private members, and also allows Constructors with parameters. But honestly I don`t know how to integrate it with RestyGWT. But maybe you should try.